# Typo3 V6.1.1 Grid Elements 2 - Can't create Content Element in Grid

Tags: typo3

I'm quite new to TYPO3, so it might be that I'm missing something obvious..
I use TYPO3 Version 6.1.1 and installed the Extension "Grid Elements 2" from the t3x File.
Then I downloaded the .zip File of the Extension to read the documentation (manual.pdf).
I edited the whole template-record of the Root-Page and included "Gridelements (gridelements)".

TYPO3 didn't ask me to update the database in any way. (I thought that, maybe, that is normal with TYPO3 v6)

But when I want to create a Grid Element as Content Element, it is just not available as option. I can create any other Element and then change it to Grid Element (But it's listed as "special element" not as Grid Element).

If I want to create any Content Element inside that Grid, the CType Column says

```
[ INVALID VALUE ("any element i choose")]
```

Is that due to some missing typoscript? I have no clue and google doesn't return any results concering my problem with my TYPO3 version.

The only thing i found was [this issue](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/49291).
I tried that patch, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that no "Grid Layout" is defined.
It's crucial that you add a "CE Backend Layout" Record, e. g. in a Storage Folder.

Then, when you create a new element, next to "Form Elements", "Plugins", there is a new tab with that Gridlayout, where you can select a gridelement with your grid-layout.